# Scrapy manually sending item to pipeline does not fire item_passed signal

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, signals

I'm trying to write a crawler which does the following job:
Start from a specific URL, then crawl the pages up to a depth limit (simple Scrapy task). During this time, check the first 1 kB of the header field, and extract the file information with [Magic](https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic). If it is a file, I want to send it to a pipeline for further processing.

What I did so far is:

```
def process_links(self, links):

    for link in links:
        try:
            req = urlopen(link.url)
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.error("--> Exception URL[%s]: %s", link, e)
            req = None

        if req is not None:
            ext_type = magic.from_buffer(req.read(1024))
            if 'HTML' in ext_type:
                yield link
            else:
                item = FileItem()
                item["type"] = "FILE"
                item["url"] = link.url
                item["extension"] = ext_type
                itemproc = self.crawler.engine.scraper.itemproc
                itemproc.process_item(item, self)
```

So I basically get the URLs from the scraped page, then depending on their type, either I yield a new Request or I send a new FileItem item to the pipeline manually (with the last two lines)

I also have parse_page function for parsing HTML pages:

```
def parse_page(self, response):

    item = PageItem()
    item["type"] = "PAGE"
    item["url"] = response.request.url
    item["depth"] = response.meta['depth']
    item["response_url"] = response.url
    item["status_code"] = response.status
    item["status_msg"] = "OK"
    item["request_headers"] = response.request.headers
    item["body"] = response.body
    item["links"] = []
    yield item
```

Which yields the PageItem object.

Although the yielded PageItem fires the item_passed signal in Scrapy, manually passed FileItems do not fire the signal. Am I missing something while manually passing the FileItems to the pipeline?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: and what's the point of passing the items manually to the pipeline? when you yield an item in a scrapy callback it goes directly to the pipeline too.

Comment: @eLRuLL, we need to understand the type of the file from the first 1 kB, and then pass it to pipeline without opening a new Request. If we yield the item inside the parse_page function (which means opening the Request, waiting for the response and copying all bytes of the file) then it would take much longer than what we do now. Because of that we prefer processing all the links in the page and once we find their type, we pass it to the pipeline manually (since we cannot yield in process_links function)